# Product list with category / subcategory name

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am beginner in Laravel. I use in my project Laravel 5.8.

I have this model:

```
class ProductCategory extends Model
{
    use scopeActiveTrait;

    protected $guarded = ['id'];
    protected $fillable = ['company_id', 'enable', 'name', 'url_address', 'level', 'parent_id', 'number'];
    public $timestamps = false;
    //protected $table = 'products_category';

    public function parent()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\ProductCategory', 'parent_id', 'id');
    }

    public function children()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\ProductCategory', 'id', 'parent_id');
    }

    public function products()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Product::class, 'product_selected_categories', 'category_id', 'product_id');
    }
}

class Product extends Model
{
    use scopeActiveTrait;

    protected $fillable = ['company_id', 'id_delivery_vat', 'id_product_vat', 'id_producer', 'name', 'qr_code', 'oe_code', 'enable', 'promo', 'description', 'product_price', 'promo_product_price', 'product_delivery_price', 'quantity', 'url_address'];
    protected $quarded = ['id'];
    public $timestamps = true;

    public function category()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\ProductCategory', 'id_producer');
    }

    public function producer()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\ProductProducer', 'id_producer');
    }

    public function selected_categories()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\ProductSelectedCategory');
    }
}

class ProductSelectedCategory extends Model
{
    protected $quarded = ['id'];
    protected $fillable = ['subcategory1_id', 'parent_subcategory1_id', 'category_id', 'subcategory2_id', 'parent_subcategory2_id', 'subcategory3_id', 'parent_subcategory3_id', 'subcategory4_id', 'parent_subcategory4_id', 'subcategory5_id', 'parent_subcategory5_id', 'subcategory6_id', 'parent_subcategory6_id', 'subcategory7_id', 'parent_subcategory7_id', 'subcategory8_id', 'parent_subcategory8_id', 'subcategory9_id', 'parent_subcategory9_id', 'product_id' ];
    public $timestamps = false;
}
```

and Schema:

```
Schema::create('products', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->bigInteger('company_id')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('company_id')->references('id')->on('companies')->onDelete('cascade');
            //$table->bigInteger('category_id')->unsigned();
            //$table->foreign('category_id')->references('id')->on('product_categories');
            $table->smallInteger('id_delivery_vat')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('id_delivery_vat')->references('id')->on('vat');
            $table->smallInteger('id_product_vat')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('id_product_vat')->references('id')->on('vat');
            $table->bigInteger('id_producer')->unsigned();
            //$table->foreign('id_producer')->references('id')->on('product_producers');
            $table->string('name', 120)->nullable();
            $table->string('qr_code', 120)->nullable();
            $table->string('oe_code', 120)->nullable();
            $table->char('enable', 1)->default(0);
            $table->char('promo', 1)->default(0);
            $table->longText('description')->nullable();
            $table->decimal('product_price', 9, 2)->default(0);
            $table->decimal('promo_product_price', 9, 2)->default(0);
            $table->decimal('product_delivery_price', 9, 2)->default(0);
            $table->unsignedInteger('quantity')->default(0);
            $table->string('url_address', 160);
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->engine = "InnoDB";
            $table->charset = 'utf8mb4';
            $table->collation = 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci';
        });

Schema::create('product_categories', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->bigInteger('company_id')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('company_id')->references('id')->on('companies')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->char('enable', 1)->default(0);
            $table->string('name', 85)->nullable();
            $table->string('url_address', 160);
            $table->integer('level')->default(0);
            //$table->bigInteger('parent_id')->default(0);
            //$table->bigInteger('parent_id')->nullable();
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('parent_id')->nullable();
            $table->foreign('parent_id')->references('id')->on('product_categories')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->bigInteger('number')->default(0);
            $table->engine = "InnoDB";
            $table->charset = 'utf8mb4';
            $table->collation = 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci';
        });

Schema::create('product_selected_categories', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->bigInteger('category_id')->unsigned()->index();
            //$table->foreign('category_id')->references('id')->on('product_categories');
            $table->bigInteger('subcategory1_id')->default(0);
            $table->bigInteger('parent_subcategory1_id')->default(0);
            $table->bigInteger('subcategory2_id')->default(0);
            $table->bigInteger('parent_subcategory2_id')->default(0);
            $table->bigInteger('subcategory3_id')->default(0);
            $table->bigInteger('parent_subcategory3_id')->default(0);
            $table->bigInteger('subcategory4_id')->default(0);
            $table->bigInteger('parent_subcategory4_id')->default(0);
            $table->bigInteger('subcategory5_id')->default(0);
            $table->bigInteger('parent_subcategory5_id')->default(0);
            $table->bigInteger('subcategory6_id')->default(0);
            $table->bigInteger('parent_subcategory6_id')->default(0);
            $table->bigInteger('subcategory7_id')->default(0);
            $table->bigInteger('parent_subcategory7_id')->default(0);
            $table->bigInteger('subcategory8_id')->default(0);
            $table->bigInteger('parent_subcategory8_id')->default(0);
            $table->bigInteger('subcategory9_id')->default(0);
            $table->bigInteger('parent_subcategory9_id')->default(0);
            $table->bigInteger('product_id')->unsigned()->index();
            $table->foreign('product_id')->references('id')->on('products')->onDelete('cascade');;
        });
```

One product can be assigned to 1 category and 8 sub-categories (product_selected_categories).

I need show product list with categories and subcategories.

I have this code to show product list:

```
Product::with(['producer', 'selected_categories'])->orderBy($sortColumn, $sortMethod)->paginate(25);

@foreach($products as $product)
{{ $product->name }} - ___product category____  - ___product subcategory1____  - ___product subcategory2____  - ___product subcategory3____ ....  - ___product subcategory8____
```

How can I display the categories and subcategories to which the product is assigned?

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is better if you have ManyToMany relation between products and categories.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many

```
class Product extends Model
{

    public function categories()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\categories');
    }
}
```

With that in mind, it would be a lot easier.

```
$product = App\Product::find(1);
foreach ($product->categories as $category) {
     //
}
```

You have many categories and many products.
Each product will have many categories, and many categories will have many products. Instead of having one row with multiple categories, you will have multiple rows with one product and one category. You can add an extra column in the pivot table if you want to add the subcategory type.

Comment: It's not working :( I have error: SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'base.product_product_category' doesn't exist (SQL: select `product_categories`.*, `product_product_category`.`product_id` as `pivot_product_id`, `product_product_category`.`product_category_id` as `pivot_product_category_id` from `product_categories` inner join `product_product_category` on `product_categories`.`id` = `product_product_category`.`product_category_id` where `product_product_category`.`product_id` = 2)